# Prove that an abelian group has a cyclic quotient

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, quotient-group

I am currently working through a problem on finite abelian groups.

Suppose we have distinct primes $p\neq q$ which both divide the order of a finite abelian group $G$. The first part asks to show that there is thus a cyclic subgroup of $G$ of order $pq$, which I have managed to do. The next part asks to prove that there is a quotient of $G$ which is cyclic and of order $pq$.

My guess is that if $H$ denotes our cyclic subgroup of order $pq$ in $G$  that the quotient should look something like
$$\frac{G}{G/H}\simeq H$$
Where we have to find a way of identifying the quotient $G/H$ with a subgroup of $G$.

Is this the right direction to take things, or should the proof follow a different line of reasoning?

Comment: Are you allowed to use the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups?

Comment: I am, yes. Would this be enough to show the quotient $G/H$ is a subgroup of $G$?

Comment: $G/H$ is not a subgroup of $G$. Its elements are cosets of $H$ in $G$, not elements of $G$, so $G/H$ is not even a subset of $G$, let alone a subgroup. It may be isomorphic to a subgroup of $G$, but it is not a subgroup of $G$. So "$G/(G/H)$" is nonsensical.

Comment: First mod out by the $(pq)'$-part of $G$, that is, the subgroup generated by all elements of $G$ of order relatively prime to $p$ and $q$. So you may assume that the only primes that divide the order of $G$ are $p$ and $q$. Then write $G$ as the sum of its $p$-part and its $q$-part (you say you know the structure theorem, so this is something you should already know). Now prove that every abelian $p$-group has a quotient isomorphic to the cyclic group of order $p$, and combine.